# Determine how long a promise took

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I'm using the q library for promises. I have the following code

```
Q.all([thumbnailPromise, createSnapshotPromise]).spread((thumbnailRep, snapshotRep) => {
```

How do I determine how long each promise took? Specifically, how long thumbnailPromise and createSnapshotPromise took separately?

Note that I want to keep the promises running in parallel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could write a function that wraps your promise:

```
const timedPromise = async (promFac) => {
    const start = performance.now();
    const returnValue = await promFac();
    return {
        value: returnValue,
        elapsed: performance.now() - start;
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Q.all([
    timedPromise(() => thumbnailPromise) , 
    timedPromise(() => createSnapshotPromise)])
  .spread((thumbnailRep, snapshotRep) => {
    console.log(`thumbnailProm took ${thumbnailRep.elapsed}, returned ${thumbnailRep.value}`);
  })
```

Untested.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `console.time()`; [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)
Another option would be to use [hrtime](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_bigint).

Promises are functions, if you don't have access directly to the functions, you can wrap them in one.